# communicating with a LPC1768 as a HID via python

Tags: python, hid, mbed

Background: I am evaluating replacing an FTDI+FPGA+RAM with a Cortex chip and I am playing around with a  LPC1768 dev card.

flashing LED? [x]
communications via a virtual comms port [x]

Now I am looking at communicating via libUSB (either CDC or HID... evaluating)

I started by trying this example: https://developer.mbed.org/cookbook/USBHID-bindings- & the **USBHID_TestCase** program compiles and runs.

The issue is on the python side (using the linux example & libUSB).

The 1st issue was the py script has:

```
mbed_vendor_id = 0x1234 
mbed_product_id = 0x0006
```

equally the mbed USBDevice:USBHID has:

```
USBHID(uint8_t output_report_length = 64, uint8_t input_report_length = 64, uint16_t vendor_id = 0x1234, uint16_t product_id = 0x0006, uint16_t product_release = 0x0001, bool connect = true);
```

ie the same product and vendor ID. However... lsusb lists the NXP chipset at a different location.

```
Bus 003 Device 008: ID 0d28:0204 NXP LPC1768
```

issuing: **lsusb -vvv  -d 0x0d28:0204** I can see 4 devices that this card exposes (good) and this is matched by a simple python testcase

```
import usb
mbed_vendor_id = 0x0d28
mbed_product_id = 0x0204
dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=mbed_vendor_id,idProduct=mbed_product_id)
```

checking what **dev** is now populated with:

```
dev[0]
<CONFIGURATION 1: 500 mA>


dev[0][(0,0)]
<INTERFACE 0: Mass Storage>
[0] <ENDPOINT 0x82: Bulk IN>
[1] <ENDPOINT 0x2: Bulk OUT>
[2] <ENDPOINT 0x0: Control OUT>


dev[0][(1,0)]
<INTERFACE 1: CDC Communication>
[0] <ENDPOINT 0x83: Interrupt IN>
[1] <ENDPOINT 0x0: Control OUT>

dev[0][(2,0)]
<INTERFACE 2: CDC Data>
[0] <ENDPOINT 0x4: Bulk OUT>
[1] <ENDPOINT 0x84: Bulk IN>
[2] <ENDPOINT 0x0: Control OUT>


dev[0][(3,0)]
<INTERFACE 3: Human Interface Device>
[0] <ENDPOINT 0x81: Interrupt IN>
[1] <ENDPOINT 0x1: Interrupt OUT>
[2] <ENDPOINT 0x0: Control OUT>
```

so 0 is mass storage -> the python script from the example wouldn't work.  I have been trying to communicate via dev[0][3,0] and by specifying an endpoint as dev[0][3,0][0] I can write but reads from dev[0][3,0][1] always return 0's even though the mbed code is meant to provide a random data.

Any idea's ?

Answer (score 1):

The USB test case code uses the usb controller on the lpc1768 ic, not the mbed board's interface chip. The code uses pin 31 and 32 on the mbed board.
Hope this helps.